# Find position vector "r"

Tags: vectors

> An object’s velocity vector, $\vec{v}$, is given by $\vec{v} = (2 + \pi \sin(\pi ))\vec{i} + 2\vec{j}.$
>
> Find its position vector, $\vec{r}$, with initial condition, $t = 0, \vec{r} = −\vec{i}+\vec{j}$.

How can I do this question? Do I have to replace t=o in vector $\vec{v}$? and dot product with $\vec{r}$? any help, please.

Comment: use $\textbf{v}=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{r}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

This is a vectorial differential equation. You just have to integrate coordinate by coordinate. Taking into account the initial vector.

Comment: I have never come across a problem like this, so i far what i understood is :
$\textbf{v}=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{r}$

$\textbf{v}=\pi^2cos(\pi t)i+2j(r=-i+j)$

can u please solve it for me?

Comment: @Ahsan So you have $x^\prime(t) \vec{i}+ y^\prime(t)\vec{j} =(2 + \pi \sin(\pi ))\vec{i} + 2\vec{j}$. You now have to separate the two coordinates and compute two integrals. I let you do that!

Comment: I don't understand what u said, but thanks for your help. I hate mathematics.

Comment: @Ahsan Are you familiar with computing integrals?

Comment: Computing integrals meaning integration with limits ?

Comment: @Ahsan Yes exactly! there are two of those to compute here... And you'll be done.

Comment: Why do I have to use integration? I don't understand, what I studied for vectors is the unit vector, scalar product, vector product and the angle between two vectors, where can I find a similar question like this on the web?

Comment: Google will be your friend! Look for vectorial differential equations.

Comment: Finally, I have done it! THANK YOU!

Comment: @Ahsan Congratulations! If on top you hate mathematics a bit less... I'm even more happy!